# Session ID lost (ajax + PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm having an issue with AJAX + PHP session ID where a new ID is getting generated by the script getting grabbed via GET. I've created 2 test scripts that expose the problem:

script 1 (commented out the AJAX, but both XMLHttpRequest and $.get() yield the same result):

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    echo('test: '.session_id());

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js?<?echo($time)?>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=this.responseText;
                    resolve('page loaded');
                }
            }
            xhr.open("GET",'http://10.1.1.101/testLinks/test2.php');
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send();
            // $.get('test2.php').done(function(val) {
            //     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=val;
            // })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Script 2:

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    echo('test2: '.session_id());
?>
```

Output:

```
test: 4occu9mq6o3c16au254grf0s56
test2: 6bk1fdbs3v2bcl9iko31s5nqp4
```

Looking at other threads, I've verified the php setting for cookies enabled, as well as the lifetime:

[php session info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Xs0.png)

I've verified that when I `include 'test2.php';` a new session ID is not generated. Only when using AJAX.

I'm not sure what else to look at here. Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT: for clarity, I'm using JQuery 3.4.0, however, after switching to XMLHttpRequest, I don't believe it's a JQuery error, and has more to do with some configuration of PHP, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Interesting, why do you include the jQuery library and then use Raw Javascript AJAX

Comment: @RiggsFolly I also used $.get() and yielded the same result. Just left it all in to show I tried using the JQuery library as well.

Comment: are you accessing this script using `http://10.1.1.101` in browser url?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes - it's the IP of the server that both scripts live on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up figuring out the issue. The server we had this deployed on was running the application through http (port 80). We generated an SSL certificate and switched over to HTTPS (port 443), and the cookies were able to hold the PHPSESSID without regenerating. This may be related to some security settings in the organization, however, but hopefully this helps someone having the same issue.